# Блокировка появления виртуальной клавиатуры

Tags: android, java

Можно ли, каким-нибудь способом блокировать выпадение виртуальной клавиатуры при нажатии на EditText?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Свойство editable:false в хмл или убрать фокус